# How to access the price of a product in SKPayment?

Tags: iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am having an In-App-Purchase for an iPhone app.

I want to display the price in the users local currency in a UILabel. For this I need the price & currency in a variable.

How can I get the price including the currency using SKPayment? (If SKPayment is correct for this use.)

I'm instantiating the product using:

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"Identifier"];
```

Thank you all in advance for your feedback!

Answer (score 120, accepted):

There's a problem with just using NSLocaleCurrencySymbol + price.stringValue:  it doesn't handle the peculiarities of different locales, eg. whether they put the currency symbol in front or not.  Norway, Denmark, Sweden and Switzerland all put their currency after, eg. 17.00Kr.  Also, most(?) European countries use ',' instead of '.' for decimals, eg. "2,99 €" rather than "€2.99".

A better plan is to use NSNumberFormatter.  The "priceLocale" that the SKProduct returned, as Ed demonstrated, is the key.  It gives NSNumberFormatter the smarts to format a price correctly.

You can also make this a lot easier by adding a new property to SKProduct using an Objective-C category.  Add the following two files to your project:

---

SKProduct+priceAsString.h:

> ```
> #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
> #import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
>
> @interface SKProduct (priceAsString)
> @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *priceAsString;
> @end
> ```

---

SKProduct+priceAsString.m:

> ```
> #import "SKProduct+priceAsString.h"
>
> @implementation SKProduct (priceAsString)
>
> - (NSString *) priceAsString
> {
>   NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
>   [formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
>   [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
>   [formatter setLocale:[self priceLocale]];
>
>   NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:[self price]];
>   [formatter release];
>   return str;
> }
>
> @end
> ```

---

Then, `#import "SKProduct+priceAsString.h"` in your code, and you should just be able to use `product.priceAsString` in code.

Comment: that is a beautiful solution, thank you for adding this! I changed the answer to your solution.

Comment: Any idea how to test this with different currencies?

Comment: Somehow this is returning "US$<amount>" for me. I notice this when I upgraded to iOS6, any ideas why?

Comment: it works, but why are you using a property instead a simple method?

Comment: Because properties are better (you can use with dot notation)

Comment: I used these code in my app, but why it always shows USD. I tried to change Language Setting on my iPhone, but didn't work. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Andy, NSNumberFormatter refers to the number-formatter behavior since OS X v10.4. It is available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Comment: s1u, In iTunes Connect, User and Roles, Add SandBox Tester, App Store Territory, you can choose the country that your tester will simulate, thus changing the currency.

Comment: Andy: some quick Googling shows that that line is probably unnecessary. I can't remember why I put it in. You could try removing it. I'm not in a position to test it at the moment.

Comment: how does this answer the actual question ?

Comment: @madoke The question being, "How to access the price of a product in SKPayment?" followed by "I want to display the price in the users local currency in a UILabel. For this I need the price & currency in a variable."

This solution - `SKProduct+priceAsString` - implements a property that returns the price and currency correctly formatted, as requested.  How _doesn't_ it answer it?

Comment: Swift version:
`let formatter = NumberFormatter();
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency;
        formatter.locale = product.priceLocale;
        priceLabel.text = formatter.string(from: product.price)`

Answer (score 9):

The correct way to determine any of that information is to use an `SKProduct` object, retrieved from the `SKProductResponse` object returned to the delegate after a call to `- (void) start` on an initialized `SKProductsRequest`.  Something like this:

```
SKProductsRequest *req = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"Identifier"]];
req.delegate = self;
[req start];

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse: (SKProductsResponse *)response {
    [request autorelease];
    if (response.products.count) {
        SKProduct *product = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLocale *priceLocale = product.priceLocale;
        NSDecimalNumber *price = product.price;
        NSString *description = product.localizedDescription;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! used it like this: myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"bla costs are %@%@", nil), [priceLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol], [price stringValue]];

Comment: thank you both! but to be a 101% correct you should use: `NSNumberFormatter* numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];` `[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior: NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];` `[numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];` `myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@ %@", nil), [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:_price], [_priceLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol]];` to fix the decimal seperator for different regions, like 2.50 $ for US and 2,50 € for European.

Comment: @Zero3nna in US you put the $ in front of the number, this puts it behind which is very strange looking for us.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the Swift version of the above answer using an `extension`:

```
extension SKProduct {
  func priceAsString() -> String {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.locale = self.priceLocale
    return formatter.string(from: self.price)! as String
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried numerous ways, but I cannot get this extension to work. I am sure I am missing something simple. Please, how do I call this extension to get a String I can put in my label?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution for Swift 3.0

```
extension SKProduct {
  func priceAsString() -> String {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.locale = self.priceLocale
    return formatter.string(from: self.price)! as String
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Works in *Swift* and *Objective-C*
- Force unwrapping is **never** your friend.
- Using computed properties creates cleaner code for Objective-C scenario because it doesn't need [] ;)

  @objc public extension SKProduct {

  ```
  var priceAsString: String? {

      let formatter = NumberFormatter()
      formatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
      formatter.numberStyle = .currency
      formatter.locale = self.priceLocale
      formatter.string(from: self.price)

      return formatter.string(from: self.price)
  }
  ```

  }

NOTE : Don't forget `import StoreKit`